# Jetpack Compose Preview fails in Multi Module app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-module, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I have a multi module app where I recently began implementing Jetpack Compose. I defined some composables to be shared by different modules. I put those in another library module and imported in relevant places. Example composable:

```
// Nothing special here, any composable function fails the same way
@Composable
fun AppTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val appColors = lightColors(
        primary = Blue
    )
    MaterialTheme(colors = appColors, content = content)
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, except said composables fail the build of the preview:

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun HistoryScreenPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        HistoryScreen()
    }
}
```

In the above example Preview works perfectly fine if I remove "AppTheme".

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.somepackage.lib.ui_theme.AppComposablesKt.AppTheme(_layoutlib_._internal_.kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2, androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int)'
at com.somepackage.feature.home.ui.history.view.HistoryFragment.HistoryScreenPreview(HistoryFragment.kt:238)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:150)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:194)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:593)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:591)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:630)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:586)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:535)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:534)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:530)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:121)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:586)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:583)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:410)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:166)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:907)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:994)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20753)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:57)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:368)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:736)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:892)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

**Android Studio version:**

- Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2
- Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Beta 3
- Dolphin 2021.3.1 Canary 5

**Compose version:** 1.1.1

Comment: I tried previewing your sample with `@Composable fun HistoryScreen() { Text("hi") }` and it works fine, Compose **1.1.1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue when it would fail at runtime as well. Turns out I didn't have the "compose = true" in the build.gradle file of the module defining AppTheme etc.  In other words, each build.gradle file requires these settings to be specified individually.

Comment: I've got the same problem, but the other module doesn't contain the android library, so I can't add `compose = true` in the gradle

Comment: @BenGooding Is that a multiplatform project?